# How to limit Google Cloud Storage resumable upload size?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I want to allow a client (browser) application to upload files directly to Google Cloud Storage while maintaining the ability to constrain the file size that the client could upload.

It's seems the best practice approach is to combine [resumable uploads](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/upload#resumable) with [signed urls](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/accesscontrol#Signed-URLs) created by a server with enough credentials (Service Account).

Is it possible, with the given flow, to limit the file size for a **specific** signed url or resumable upload id? Meaning that Google Cloud Storage would reject a file that exceeds a desired size.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to limit a signed URL to an *exact* allowed size by adding a [Content-Length canonical extension header](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control#About-CanonicalExtensionHeaders). This will make only uploads with that exact content-length allowed (and will not allow chunked encoding uploads which do not have that header.  You could thus have your client pass in the desired length to the service that provides the signed URL, which then includes this limit.

Comment: I think that link may have broken, is this correct? https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls#about-canonical-extension-headers